# How can I sleep on my back instead of my side or stomach?

Tags: comfort, sleeping

How can I fall and stay asleep on my back instead of my side or stomach? I have a hard time falling asleep on my back and even when I do, I always wake up on my side or stomach.

Comment: I am sure most people (more accurately, those who sleep in the same room as them) have the opposite problem.

Comment: Try supplementing with ZMA or atleast magnesium(800+), may make you move less while you sleep..

Comment: Could you explain what the problem is with sleeping on the side/stomach? Lots of people sleep like that.

Comment: @sleske - after a cornea transplantation operation, for instance, one is sometimes advised to sleep on his back for awhile, so as not to press one's eye inadvertently against something and thus cause some issue with the transplant.

Answer (score 2):

Try placing pillows on each side of you. This may help you from being able to roll over in the middle of the night. Another solution would be to sleep in a recliner or chair that you are forced to sleep in one position.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this problem since childhood. I always wanted to sleep on my back instead of side or stomach.

***The pillow approach is also useful.***

This approach worked for me and may or may not work for you:

Once I lay down on bed, I start to imagine myself sleeping on my back entire night and seeing myself in same position in morning.

It took around a year to see good results for me.

***This is a solution which takes time to see results and you need patience.***

Thanks.